# Add multiple columns with dplyr and fill cells based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to:

1) add multiple columns that correspond to existing columns (e.g., a1 exists and add a1_yes).

2) Next, if a given cell contains 1:3, put 1 in a#_yes column, otherwise, put 0.

I can easily to this with base R but I'm trying to also make it work with **dplyr**.

My data:

```
df <- data.frame(a1 = c(1, 2, 0, NA, NA),
                 a2 = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 3))
```

With base R:

```
df[paste0("a", 1:2, "_yes")] <- NA  # add columns       
for(c in 1:2) {
      for(r in 1:nrow(df)) {
      ifelse(df[r,c] %in% c(1,2,3), df[r,c+2] <- 1,df[r,c+2] <-  0) 
      }
    }
    > df
      a1 a2 a1_yes a2_yes
    1  1 NA      1      0
    2  2  1      1      1
    3  0  2      0      1
    4 NA  3      0      1
    5 NA  3      0      1
```

Thank you

Comment: Just a heads up (not that you asked), in base R it would be a little more efficient to use `lapply()` instead of nested `for` loops: `df[paste0("a", 1:2, "_yes")] <- lapply(df, function(x) +(x %in% c(1:3)))`. You could swap out `+` for `as.integer()` to be more explicit. Or you could use `ifelse()` if you prefer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option, assuming you want to do this to all columns of your dataframe

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
mutate_all(., list('yes' = ~ifelse(.x %in% c(1:3), 1, 0)))

#  a1 a2 a1_yes a2_yes
#1  1 NA       1       0
#2  2  1       1       1
#3  0  2       0       1
#4 NA  3       0       1
#5 NA  3       0       1
```

#### Edits

As @Akrun mentioned, you can do this without `ifelse` using `as.integer` or `+`

```
df %>%
mutate_all(., list('yes' = ~as.integer(.x %in% 1:3)))
```

You can also use `mutate_at` to select specific `vars`

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(a1, a2), list('yes' = ~as.integer(.x %in% 1:3)))
```

Comment: you should just remove the underscore in ```list``` since ```mutate_all``` automatically adds one

Comment: Not sure why `ifelse` is needed `~as.integer(.x %in% 1:3)`

Comment: Can this sill be done while selecting columns in the dataset? I've tried without success  df %>%   dplyr::mutate_at(dplyr::select(.,a1,a2), list('yes' = ~as.integer(.x %in% 1:3)))

Comment: @EML you have to use `vars`. I'll edit the answer and add that in

Answer (score 2):

This will work without editing no matter how many columns you have if they are all in this format

```
df %>% 
      mutate_all(., function(x) ifelse(x == 0 | is.na(x), 0, 1)) %>%
      rename_all(., function(x) paste0(x, "_yes")) %>%
      bind_cols(df, .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a1 = c(1, 2, 0, NA, NA),
                 a2 = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 3))

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(a1_yes = ifelse(a1 == 0 | is.na(a1), 0, 1),
         a2_yes = ifelse(a2 == 0 | is.na(a2), 0, 1))
```

Instead of putting the conditions so that the new columns' values are 1, I put the conditions so that they're equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
 df <- data.frame( a1 = c(1,2,0,NA,NA),
                   a2 = c(NA,1,2,3,3))

check_values <- c(1,2,3)

df %>% mutate(a1_yes = ifelse(a1 %in% check_values,1,0),
              a2_yes =ifelse(a2 %in% check_values,1,0))
```